# Problem with setReult and onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-widget

In my android app I'm opening a new activity for result when a button is pressed:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(parent.this.getApplication(), child.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

My child activity returns a result like this:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent();
newIntent.putExtra("name", "name");
newIntent.putExtra("description", "desc");
setResult(RESULT_OK, newIntent);
finish();
```

My onActivityResult is like this:

```
if (requestCode == GOTO_ADDPARKING) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         String Name = data.getStringExtra("name");
         String Description = data.getStringExtra("description");
```

In the debug mode I can see that in the child activity the newIntent's hash map points to an object, but in the parent activity the hash map points to null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be that REQUEST_CODE is not equal to GOTO_ADDPARKING ?

Comment: No. they're the same, equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but try to use createPendingResult(int, Intent, int) instead of create creating a new intent

```
Intent newIntent = new createPendingResult(...);
```

(from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)